how to get link field's value with hook_views_pre_render?
I have a content type names Link in which contains only a link field. I want to rewrite the title link to the external link(link field's value),but I couldn't get link field's value under hook_views_pre_render, although I could get title,body,created... value without any problem ,I just couldn't get the value of link field which I added to the content type.
core: Drupal 10

Blockquote
Drupal\views\ResultRow {#11171 ▼
+_entity:
Drupal\node\Entity

Node {#11292 ▼
#entityTypeId: "node"
#enforceIsNew: null
#typedData: null
#cacheContexts: []
#cacheTags: []
#cacheMaxAge: -1
#_serviceIds: []
#_entityStorages: []
#values: array:21 [▼
"nid" => array:1 [▶]
"vid" => array:1 [▶]
"type" => array:1 [▶]
"uuid" => array:1 [▶]
"langcode" => array:1 [▶]
"revision_uid" => array:1 [▶]
"revision_timestamp" => array:1 [▶]
"revision_log" => array:1 [▶]
"revision_default" => array:1 [▶]
"isDefaultRevision" => array:1 [▶]
"status" => array:1 [▶]
"uid" => array:1 [▶]
"title" => array:1 [▶]
"created" => array:1 [▶]
"changed" => array:1 [▶]
"promote" => array:1 [▶]
"sticky" => array:1 [▶]
"default_langcode" => array:1 [▶]
"revision_translation_affected" => array:1 [▶]
"field_comment2" => array:1 [▶]
"field_link" => array:1 [▶]
]
#fields: []
#fieldDefinitions: null
#languages: null
#langcodeKey: "langcode"
#defaultLangcodeKey: "default_langcode"
#activeLangcode: "x-default"
#enforceDefaultTranslation: null
#defaultLangcode: "en"
#translations: array:1 [▶]
#translationInitialize: false
#newRevision: false
#isDefaultRevision: "1"
#entityKeys: array:4 [▶]
#translatableEntityKeys: array:8 [▶]
#validated: false
#validationRequired: false
#loadedRevisionId: "214"
#revisionTranslationAffectedKey: "revision_translation_affected"
#enforceRevisionTranslationAffected: []
#isSyncing: false
+in_preview: null
}
+_relationship_entities: array:1 [▶]
+index: 0
+"node_field_data_created": "1718470654"
+"nid": "214"
+"users_field_data_node_field_data_uid": "36"
}
...
Blockquote

function showcontent_views_pre_render(ViewExecutable $view){


    // Check if we are working with the correct view and display.
    if ($view->id() == 'newest' ) {
        // Iterate through the rendered result to find the title field and rewrite it.

        foreach ($view->result as $key => $row) {
    

            if($row->_entity->hasField('field_link')){

                $current_title = $row->_entity->get('title')->value;
                dpm($current_title); //get node title
                $external_link_uri = $row->_entity->get('field_link')->value;
                dpm($external_link_uri); //get null value



            }else{

            }


        }

    }
}


Well, I solved it by myself just now , I am not sure if this is the best way though, if you have a better way, it would be appreciated you can post it here.
my way:~
function showcontent_views_pre_render(ViewExecutable $view){


// Check if we are working with the correct view and display.
if ($view->id() == 'newest' ) {
    // Iterate through the rendered result to find the title field and rewrite it.

    foreach ($view->result as $key => $row) {
        dpm($row);

        if($row->_entity->hasField('field_link')){

            $current_title = $row->_entity->get('title')->value;
            dpm($current_title); //get node title
            $external_link_uri = $row->_entity->get('field_link')->first()->getValue()['uri'];   // this is the trick
            dpm($external_link_uri); //get uri value
  


        }else{

        }

    }

}

}

You can write it much shorter:
$node = $row->_entity;
if ($node->getType() == 'link') {
  $title = $node->title->value;
  $uri = $node->field_link->uri;

For the link field type the database column containing the field data is uri.

In fact,I tested "$row->field_link->uri;"  before I posted this question, it wouldn't work and returned null for uri value. Thanks!

This code is missing _entity. You better do it step by step. First get $node, then check if it is the content type and then you can be sure you find the fields added to this content type.

I did has _entity on the script but it wouldn't work for link field , returned result was null.
